# Problema con los metodos y constructor?

Tags: java

Tengo un pequeño código en la cual el propósito es verificar el nombre del usuario y ver si existe en un array y la edad verificar si es mayor de edad. Si lo es, está autorizado a entrar al sistema.

El código no está terminado aún pero mi duda es que tengo un método de tipo `String` que recibe un parámetro llamado `name` que está en otra clase y es heredada a través de la clase principal llamada `MyName` tengo dos campos definidos `private` (los deberia definir asi o public porque los usara el metodo de la otra clase) ,bueno despues en la clase principal defino un constructor por el cual definiar (iniciara) por defecto los valores ahi esta mi otro problema tengo dos objetos un objeto tipo String y otro tipo ID los beria definir asi o como?

Aquí está el código para que vean lo que llevo:

Clase principal

```
/*Proposito del programa:
 el proposito del programa es verificar el name del usuario y ver si exsite en un array y la edad 
 verificar si es mayor de edad si lo es es autorizado a entrar al sistema.
*/

public Class MyClass extends Methods {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
    //Campos 
        private String name;
        private int edad;

        //Creo los objetos name(nombre) y edad(la edad del usuario)
        String user = new String();
        id edad = new id();
        /* Mi problema es aqui en los objetos deberia crearlos asi o como ?*/
        //Constructor 
        public MyClass {
            user.Getname = "Gilberto quintero";
        }
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);   
    }    
}
```

La otra clase

```
public Class Methods {
    public String Getname(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hola bienvenido a"+name);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque me ha costado entender lo que pides, creo que esto es lo más correcto según tus necesidades. He comentado el código de tal manera que espero que entiendas el funcionamiento del programa sin problemas.

Clase Methods:

```
public class Methods{

  /* Método que comprueba si nombre esta en el array
  *  Si esta: Saluda
  *  Si no esta: avisa de que no es valido el nombre
  *  El array si le pasa como parametro (Asi te vale para otros casos)
  *  El nombre se le pasa como parametro
  *  Si el método saluda, ¿para que va a devolver nada? => el metodo es void
  */
  public static void getName(String nombre, String[] array){
      boolean esta = false;
      // Lo busco en el array desde la primera posicion a la ultima, si lo encuentro paro
      for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length && !esta ; i++) // Va hasta el final buscando nombre, si lo encuentra para
          if(nombre.equals(array[i])) // Como String son OBJETOS se usa EQUALS
              esta = true;
      if(esta) // es equivalente a esta == true
          System.out.println("Bienvenido: " + nombre);
      else
          System.out.println(nombre + " no esta en la base de datos");
  }
}
```

Clase MyName que hereda de Methods el método que busca en el array

```
// para poder usar el Scanner lo tenemos que tener, lo importamos
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyName extends Methods{

  /* Metodo principal del programa: aqui empieza el programa
  *  El programa o se conecta a una base de datos de verdad o 
  *  tiene que saber que usuarios son validos y cuales no. 
  *  Creamos el array nosotros para hacer la prueba
  *  El array se puede crear dentro aunque por convenio mejor fuera
  */
  public static void main(String[] args){
      /* Para pedir cosas por teclado al usuario necesitamos Scanner */
      Scanner  teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Necesitamos dos variables para guardar el nombre y la edad
      String nombre;
      int edad;

      // Se los pedimos la usuario
      System.out.print("Por favor, introduzca su nombre para entrar al sistema: ");
      nombre = teclado.nextLine(); // Pedimos texto con espacios
      System.out.print("Por favor, introduzca su edad para entrar al sistema: ");
      edad = teclado.nextInt(); // Pedimos un numero

      if(edad < 18)
          System.out.println("No permitido a menores de edad");
      else
          getName(nombre, array);
  }

  /* Aunque no lo veamos el método getName(nombre, array) esta aqui */

  /* Creamos el array, aqui o arriba da igual aunque mas intuitivo arriba */

  private static String[]  array = {"Alonso" , "Jaime" , "Rodrigo"};
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda y te aclare los conceptos. Cualquier duda que tengas pregunta!

Answer (score 2):

Existen algunos errores.

- Un constructor es un método para iniciar una clase no debe de estar dentro de un método como es el caso que pusiste en un main.
- Los atributos de clase se definen fuera de un método.
- Class no se usa para definir una clase en Java. En java es case sensitive. No es lo mismo class y Class. Lo correcto sería *public class MyClass extends Methods{}*
- Generalmente por convención un método se escribe en minúsculas. Si tiene palabras compuestas se escribe algo similar a getName. No es obligatorio de esta forma, pero la mayoría de los desarrolladores Java escriben así.
- Generalmente una clase se definen los valores y con sus respectivos métodos. En otra clase se define el método main. Pero ya depende de tus necesidades. No es estricto.
- La herencia es para extender una clase. En mi ejemplo no utilizo, pero te dejo un [link](http://jarroba.com/herencia-en-la-programacion-orientada-a-objetos-ejemplo-en-java/) que te va a servir mucho.

Te muestro en ejemplo mas o menos para que te fijes y amplíes a tus necesidades

Ejemplo:

La clase MyClass

```
public class MyClass{
    // Campos 
    private String name;
    private int edad;

    // Constructor 
    public MyClass(String name, int edad){
        // Se guardan el name y la edad en la clase en sus respectivos atributos.
        this.name = name;
        this.edad = edad;
    }  

    public String getName(String name) {
        return this.name;
    } 

    public int getEdad(int edad) {
        return this.edad;
    } 

    public String saludo(String saludo) {
        String name_tmp = saludo + " " + name;
        System.out.println(name_tmp);
        return this.name;
    } 
}
```

La clase Methods

```
public class Methods {
     public static void main(String[]args) {
         // Crear un objeto MyClass
         MyClass miPrimeraClase = new MyClass("Jose", 31);

         // Saludo.
         miPrimeraClase.saludo("Hola bienvenido a");
     }
}
```

Obs:

- En la clase MyClass no agregue los métodos set de cada atributo. La idea de mi ejemplo para que amplíes a tus necesidades y tengas un código que funcione.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios :)

Answer (score 1):

No acababa de entender bien tu código y lo que pones en el propopósito lo que podido hacer con dos sencillas clases Java.

**Usuario.java**

```
public class Usuario
{
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    private static final int MAYORIA_EDAD = 18;

    public Usuario(String nombre, int edad)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    boolean menor()
    { return edad < MAYORIA_EDAD; }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    { return nombre + " - " + edad + " años"; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null)
            return false;
        else if(obj instanceof Usuario == false)
            return false;
        else
        {
            Usuario usr = (Usuario) obj;
            return this.nombre.equals(usr.nombre);
        }
    }
}
```

**Aplicacion.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Aplicacion
{
    // Uso un ArrayList porque me gusta más
    private ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios;

    public Aplicacion()
    {
        usuarios = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void nuevoUsuario(Usuario usr)
    { usuarios.add( usr ); }

    public boolean autorizar(Usuario usr)
    {
        boolean encontrado = false;
        for (Usuario u : usuarios) 
        {
            if( u.equals(usr) )
                encontrado = true;
        }
        // Si buscar se puede hacer de forma más eficiente, pero no quiero liarme con esto

        if(encontrado)
        {
            if( usr.menor() )
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Aplicacion app = new Aplicacion();
        Usuario usrMayor = new Usuario("jpuriol", 20);
        Usuario usrMenor = new Usuario("peque", 10);

        System.out.print("Añadiendo nuevos usuarios");

        app.nuevoUsuario(usrMayor);
        app.nuevoUsuario(usrMenor);

        System.out.println("**hecho**");

        System.out.print("**El usuario " + usrMayor + " intenta entrar**");
        boolean autorizacion1 = app.autorizar(usrMayor);
        System.out.println("RESULTADO: " + autorizacion1);

        System.out.print("**El usuario " + usrMenor + " intenta entrar**");
        boolean autorizacion2 = app.autorizar(usrMenor);
        System.out.println("RESULTADO: " + autorizacion2);

        // Falta probar el caso de que no se encuentre
    }
}
```

No responde directamente a tu pregunta pero espero que te ayude.